# Is there a way to switch on/off std:cerr (or equivalent)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Without using a full-blown logging library (or IF statements) - is there a way in C++ to sometimes print out messages to the console and sometimes not?

I am using `std::cerr`, is there a way to control when this outputs or not?

Ideally I could have:

```
std::cerr << "Constructor called" << endl;
```

and have a way to enable/disable this line of code?

Comment: When is that line called and when should it not be called?

Comment: Maybe this is only about making program silent by silencing all atderr output? Does running `program 2>nul` gives desired functionality?

Comment: I just want to use it for debugging (I probably shouldnt be using cerr, as it indicates error).

Comment: @kworr yes this is about having a way to turn on/off debugging messages.

Comment: You want to turn it on or off without `if`? What do you mean by turn on or off then? A decision usually requires an `if`.

Comment: It might be a better approach to wrap `cerr` and `clog` in some kind of logging facility. Then you can programmatically disable the logging facility, or redirect the logging to a file if you choose. It doesn't have to be very complex - a simple wrapper can be as small as 50 lines of code.

Comment: Just create a small wrapper class that provides access to a `std::ostream` reference you choose internally dependent on a log on/off attribute.

Comment: @jxh I think the OP meant to avoid writing an `if` statement for each and every line when he wants to print a log message.

Comment: @greyfade: `cerr` and `clog` already are "some type of logging facility" that provides those capabilities.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I mean a specialized logging facility that perhaps includes additional text and features and handles error control transparently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "without `if`", but you can write code without using the `if` yourself. A macro can check a flag for you.

```
#define CERR if (cerr_disabled) {} else std::cerr
bool cerr_disabled = false;
```

Then, in your code:

```
CERR << "error message" << std::endl;
```

If `cerr_disabled` is true, then nothing is printed.

The advantage of this macro approach is that none of the print arguments get evaluated if the err logging is disabled. For instance, if you needed to call a function to create a more complicated log string:

```
std::string fancy_log_message () {
    //...
}

CERR << fancy_log_message();
```

If `cerr_disabled` is true, `fancy_log_message()` is not called. This is something that can't be achieved by just suppressing the stream object itself.

Comment: Actually had the same idea this moment.

Answer (score 3):

The simple approach is to set/clear `std::ios_base::failbit` on the stream: while `std::ios_base::failbit` is set, the streams won't do any work [unless the output operators are written incorrectly]:

```
std::cerr.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
std::cerr << "this won't show\n";
std::cerr.clear();
std::cerr << "this will show!\n";
```

To make these operations easier to use you can create manipulators, e.g.:

```
std::ostream& stream_on(std::ostream& out) {
    out.clear();
    return out;
}
std::ostream& stream_off(std::ostream& out) {
    out.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    return out;
}

std::cerr << stream_off << "not printed\n" << stream_on << "printed\n";
```

If you really want to disable the stream even if the output operators are badly implemented, you can save the current `rdbuf()` (e.g., in a suitable `std::ostream::pword()`) and set the stream buffer to `nullptr`:

```
static int stream_off_index() { static int rc = std::ios_base::xalloc(); return rc; }
std::ostream& stream_on(std::ostream& out) {
    out.pword(stream_off_index) = out.rdbuf(nullptr);
    return out;
}
std::ostream& stream_off(std::ostream& out) {
    if (!out.rdbuf()) {
        out.rdbuf(out.pword(stream_off_index);
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: This avoids using a macro, but you pay the expense of invoking the `<<` operator on each argument just to do nothing.

Comment: @jxh: In addition to avoiding a macro it also means that existing output to `std::cerr` doesn't need to be touched: once `std::cerr` is set up as disabled/enabled, on other code is affected. ... but, yes, all arguments are evaluated (and the corresponding side-effects are applied) and the operators are called.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without macros:

```
#include <iostream>

void toggle_cerr()
{
    static std::streambuf* p = std::cerr.rdbuf();

    std::cerr.rdbuf(std::cerr.rdbuf() ? nullptr : p);
}

int main()
{
    toggle_cerr();
    std::cerr << "str";
}
```

Comment: The disadvantage of this approach is that the `<<` operator is still invoked for each argument even if disabled.